# sLDA for predicting categorical response instead of continuous in R

Tags: r, tm, lda, topic-modeling

I have a collection of documents, that might have latent topics associated with them. It is likely that each document might relate to one or more topics. I have a master file of all possible "topics"/categories and descriptions to these topics. I am seeking to create a model that predicts the topics for each document.

I could potentially use Supervised text classification using RTextTools, but that would only help me categorize documents to belong to one category or another. I am seeking to find a solution that would not only help me determine the topic proportions to the document, but also give the term-topic/category distributions.
sLDA seems like a good fit, but it seems to only predict continuous variable outcomes instead of categorical.

Comment: It might be better to post this on Cross Validated as it's more of a methodological vs. programming question.

Answer (score 1):

LDA is more of a classification method, predicting classes. other methods can be multinational logistic regression. LDA could be harder to train compared to Multinational, given a possible little improved fit it can provide.

update: LDA is a classification method where unlike logistic regression that you directly predict Pr(Y = k|X = x) using the logit link, LDA uses the Bayes theorem for prediction. It is normally a more popular compared to logistic regression (and its extension for multi-class prediction, namely multinational logistic regression) for multi-class problems.
LDA assumes that the observations are drawn from a Gaussian distribution with a common covariance matrix in each class, and so can provide some improvements over logistic regression when this assumption approximately holds. in contrast,it is suggested that logistic regression can outperform LDA if these Gaussian assumptions are not hold. To sum up, While both are appropriate for the development of linear classification models, linear discriminant analysis makes more assumptions about the underlying data as opposed to logistic regression, which makes logistic regression a more flexible and robust method when these assumptions are not hold. So what I meant was, it is important to understand your data well, and see which might fit your data better. There are good sources on read you can read and comparison of classification methods:
http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20Seventh%20Printing.pdf 
I suggest Introduction to statistical learning, on classification chapter. Hope this helps

Comment: I am not sure I understand, could you kindly elaborate?